# Mysql multiple like queries are not working and giving 504 error

Tags: mysql

Please check my mysql query. This query is taking long time and goes to 504 error page. I am just searching keyword in text type column.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count FROM attachment
   LEFT JOIN candidate
          ON attachment.data_item_id = candidate.candidate_id
             AND attachment.site_id = candidate.site_id
             AND ( candidate.is_admin_hidden = 0 )
             AND ( candidate.is_active = 1 ) WHERE  ( ( ( attachment.text LIKE '%JAVA DEVELOPER%' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '%JAVA PROGRAMMER %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% JAVA ENGINEER %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% JAVA CONSULTANT %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% JAVA LEAD %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% J2EE DEVELOPER %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% J2EE CONSULTANT %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% J2EE LEAD %' )
        OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% J2EE PROGRAMMER%' ) )
     AND ( attachment.text LIKE '% INJECTION %' )
     AND ( ( attachment.text LIKE '%ASYNC %' )
            OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% REACTIVE%' ) )
     AND ( attachment.text LIKE '% SPRING %' )
     AND ( ( attachment.text LIKE '%MONGODB %' )
            OR ( attachment.text LIKE '% MONGO DB%' ) )
     AND ( attachment.text LIKE '% KAFKA%' )
     AND ( attachment.text LIKE '%REDIS%' ) )
```

Comment: A big `like` query is not a good idea. How about you store the "expertise" in another table and join it to candidates?

Comment: Text column has very large data. It has resume text data so how can i store expertise in separate table. Can i store text column data in new table ?